# Prevent object stored in ArrayList from being over written

Tags: java

Basically I have to write a simple contact manager, and store objects in array list.

What frustrates me is that I have newContact method, which when called creates new instance of Contact, and stores it in ArrayList. The problem is that every time I call that method, all other objets in the list gets overwritten.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ContactManager {

  public static ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
  public static Contact[]c = {};

  public static void main(String[]args){
    newContact();
    newContact();

    System.out.println(contactList.get(1).getName());
    System.out.println(contactList.get(0).getName());
  }

  public static void newContact(){
    Contact c = new Contact();
    contactList.add(c);
  }
}
```

In Contact class constructore there is code that initializes the object's properties using Scanner class.

If in first call I Enter "John" and in second function call I enter "Peter", the above code will print out:

Peter
Peter.

Why doesn't it prints out John Peter?

Only thing I can think of is that maybe Java stores only reference to object in arraylist, and that unlike variables objects don't get destroyed after function executes..

Any ways around this?

I hope this explains what I am trying to achieve.

PS. I know people hate people that as homework questions. But I am doing this as an extra, in order to learn new stuff. Original assignment barely asks to instantiate 5 objects and store them in ArrayList. And I have that done, now I am just trying to see if I could come up with more dynamic solution.

Contact class code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Contact{

```
private static String name, number;

//constructor will ask to enter contact details
public Contact(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter name:");
    name = in.next();

    System.out.println("Enter number:");
    number = in.next();
}

//getters and setters

public static String getName(){
    return name;
}

public static String getNumber(){
    return number;
}

public static void setName(String newName){
    name = newName;
}

public static void setNumber(String newNumber){
    number = newNumber;
}

}
```

Comment: It should print John Peter. The error is with your code. Can you show us the code for `Contact()`?

Comment: Please show us the code that initialises the properties.

Comment: The fact that the contact list was declared as `static` might cause the problem, I can't tell for sure without looking the code.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I dont think static has anything to do with it. it wont create a problem in this case

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: I agree with Edge - it's not the best OO design, but I don't believe that's where the problem is.

Comment: There is no evidence of your problem in the current code, better diagnosis could be made by taking a look at how you are actually creating the contacts. It appears that you're actually putting two contacts named Peter in the list, and not that you're seeing the same contact twice.

Comment: @twain249 ok, i have pasted in the code for contacts now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the members in the `Contact` class are static.  That means that all `Contact` instances share the same `name` and `number`.  You should make them instance members so that each time you do `new Contact` you get a new copy of these variables.